# Android. Как изменить стиль текста в string.xml? Например сделать его жирным?

Tags: java, android, строки

Попробовал заключить текст `<b></b>`, но нет никакого эффекта??

```
 <string-array name="opisanString">
    <item> <b>жирный шрифт</b> </item>
<item><i>наклонный шрифт</i>  </item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: так должно работать. А как вы используете ваш `string-array`

Comment: Получаю из ресурса String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titleString);
Затем в БД, а после уже размещаю. Я думаю, может как-то БД сбивает стиль??

Answer (score 2):

Вместо такого объявления массива:

```
String[] str = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
```

Попробуй использовать такой вариант:

```
CharSequence[] str = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.testArray);
```

Должно заработать.

Comment: Спасибо я попробовал, но сама архитектура приложение так замудренна, что текс сейчас перестал отображаться может, что-то упустил. Буду разбираться

Answer (score 2):

Создай в `strings.xml` две стринги

```
<string name="stringa1"><i>курсивом</i></string>
<string name="stringa2"><b>жирным</b></string>
```

А потом создавай стринг-массив

```
   <string-array name="opisanString">
    <item>@string/stringa1</item>
    <item>@string/stringa2 </item>
   </string-array>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но тоже самое